# Why is there no No:6 in the movie "6 Underground"?

Tags: plot-explanation, 6-underground

In the Ryan Reynolds movie *6 Underground* each person is called by a no. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7. There is no 6.

Ryan Reynolds's character put the team together and he gave others the corresponding numbers.

Even in the movie, someone at one point asks, One aka Ryan Reynolds, why there is no Six. But he didn't answer it.

So why is there no six?  Is it mentioned in the movie?

Comment: Did you watch the movie?

Comment: agreed with @EgeBayrak - it's quite clearly shown in the beginning of the film. Maybe OP arrived late to the screening?

Comment: @AaronF - If you miss the 3-4 second identification shot (~00:06:10 into the film) that I put into my response, Six is only obliquely referred to. Since he died around the 00:19:00 mark, he also doesn't have the number identified flashback vignettes that build background for the others.

Comment: @Jeeped good point, well made! :-) though, for me, 6's death was a bit shocking and memorable as it happened quite early in the film, so was still fresh in my mind when 7 asked 1 why he wasn't called 6 (not sure when that happened, but don't think it was very long after 6 died)

Comment: @AaronF - I believe the moment you are referring to is ~00:27:40 when 1 & 7 leave Arlington. 1: *From now on you'll be known as 7. I'm 1.* 7: *So there are seven of us?* 1:  *No. Six.*

Comment: @Jeeped that's it. Less than 10 minutes later. Then again, most of the film felt to me like the cut-scenes before missions in the Call of Duty games, so I imagine that a lot of flashy _stuff_ happened in that time :-)

Comment: Because seven ate nine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The role of Six is credited to [Dave Franco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Franco). Six was the driver for the original anonymous vigilante squad.

[image]
    <sub>Dave Franco's unnamed character is introduced on-screen at ~00:06:10 into the film.</sub>

- [One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z2Ju.jpg) - Mastermind and organizer of the squad (unnamed American billionaire/philanthropist played by [Ryan Reynolds](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005351/))
- [Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS5cg.jpg) - CIA Spook (Camille played by [Mélanie Laurent](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0491259/))
- [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEfgN.png) - The Hitman (Javier played by [Manuel Garcia-Rulfo](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2636310/))
- [Four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xna3g.png) - The Skywalker (Billy, a [parkour runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour) and thief played by [Ben Hardy](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5228887/))
- [Five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjj2H.jpg) - The Doctor (Amelia played by [Adria Arjona](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5245722/))
- Six - The Driver (unnamed character played by [Dave Franco](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2002649/))

> On their first mission in Florence, Italy, the team kills the lawyer of Turgistan's four generals before they are chased across the city by the Mafia and the police. **Six is killed just as they manage to get away**. Days later, One recruits former Delta Force sniper Blaine and renames him "Seven".
>   <sub>*source:* [6 Underground - Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_Underground_(film)#Plot)</sub>

- Seven - The Sniper (Blaine played by [Corey Hawkins](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3659660/))

There's a little more from Netflix's [6 Underground Cast & Character Backstory Guide](https://screenrant.com/6-underground-movie-cast-character-backstory-guide/),

> Dave Franco As Six:
> The **unnamed team driver** who dies in a car accident during a Florence mission. After the driver's death, One reminds everybody that they weren't the deceased's "family," nor are they a "family" unit. **Nothing else is revealed about the driver**.
>   <sub>*source:* [Netflix's 6 Underground Cast & Character Backstory Guide](https://screenrant.com/6-underground-movie-cast-character-backstory-guide/)</sub>

[image]
    <sub>Six driving the squad prior to the fatal crash.</sub>